# Sending a &Path into a thread, argument requires that args is borrowed for 'static

Tags: rust, thread-safety, lifetime

So im trying to get more comfortable with threads and channels in rust, and decided to revisit the 'sum a bunch of numbers with multiple threads' problem that I did in C a long time ago. I have all the logic down, but I cant seem to pass the path of the file to open to my threads. I have:

```rust
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let path = Path::new(&args[0]);
    let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let filelen = file.metadata().unwrap().len();

    let mut markers: [Option<u64>; NUMTHREADS - 1] =
        core::array::from_fn(|i| Some((filelen / 4) * i as u64 + 1));

    markers = markers.map(|m| advance_to_next_line(&mut file, m.unwrap()));

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<u64>();
    let mut children = vec![];
    for i in 0..NUMTHREADS {
        let thread_tx = tx.clone();
        //edge cases
        let start = if i == 0 { 0 } else { markers[i - 1].unwrap() };
        let end = if i == NUMTHREADS {
            filelen
        } else {
            markers[i - 1].unwrap()
        };
        children.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            thread_tx.send(sum_between_markers(&path, &start, &end))
        }))
    }
    println!("{}", rx.iter().sum::<u64>());
    let _ = children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join().unwrap());
}
```

(not putting whole thing for brevity, but the signature for sum_between_markers is `fnsum_between_markers(path: &Path, start: &u64, end: &u64) -> u64`)

this causes cargo to give me:

```
cargo check
    Checking tmp v0.1.0 (/home/gabe/tmp)
error[E0597]: `args` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:44:27
   |
43 |       let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
   |           ---- binding `args` declared here
44 |       let path = Path::new(&args[0]);
   |                             ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
64 |           children.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   |  _______________________-
65 | |             thread_tx.send(sum_between_markers(&path, &start, &end))
66 | |         }))
   | |__________- argument requires that `args` is borrowed for `'static`
...
70 |   }
   |   - `args` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `tmp` (bin "tmp") due to previous error
```

I expected that since &path was an immutable reference, all would be well, but that is obviously not the case. Im also surprised that rust is not also complaining about the start and end parameters.

I did try passing `path` as owned and cloning it inside the loop the way I do with `thread_tx`, but as `Path` is not sized, it must be passed in as a reference.

I also tried wrapping `path` in an `Arc`, but that ran into problems with the first call to File::open, as `Arc<&Path>` does not implement `AsRef<Path>`.

Comment: One solution is to use [scoped thread](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html), so that the compiler will know that you wait for all the threads to complete before dropping `args`.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about scoped threads. Sorry about the duplicate, guessing I didnt find it because I was looking for keywords like 'borrowed' or '`static'